# Trying to integration Google Nearby Message API in android project

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-nearby, android-developer-api

I am trying to use google nearby message API in my android project with the help of google nearby message documentation (the link is given below) but did't get any output, there is errors in my android project i will add the code below.

I have searched about this nearby message API on google but could't found anything useful, i am newbie in android development field.can anyone give me the proper documentation that can explain me everything about this API or at least give me sample code or any example to understand the process.

And yes i have one doubt, without using Beacon Hardware can i use Nearby message API?

google nearby message documentation - https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview

Error code -

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).publish(mMessage);
    Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).subscribe(mMessageListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).unpublish(mMessage);
    Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).unsubscribe(mMessageListener);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Explanation- i have followed the steps as given in nearby message API documentation but getting error "getMessagesClient(this)" in this syntax.

i would appreciate if someone could help me on this matter. thank you so much.

Image : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2cQl.png)

Comment: It needs an activity as argument. Are you using it in activity?

Comment: No, I am using in Fragment.

Comment: i have added the answer

Comment: it is not working, I am getting same error..
#Rahul Khurana I have added image of code.

Comment: answer updated .

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

You may need to implement a listener of this.

```
Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).unpublish(mMessage);
```

and hit **alt+enter**, then it will suggest you to implement **MessageListener** to your fragment

**EDIT**

```
Nearby.getConnections(this).startAdvertising(
      getUserNickname(),
      SERVICE_ID,
      mConnectionLifecycleCallback,
      new AdvertisingOptions(STRATEGY))
  .addOnSuccessListener(
    new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Void unusedResult) {
        // We're advertising!
      }
    })
  .addOnFailureListener(
    new OnFailureListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        // We were unable to start advertising.
      }
    });
```

Comment: OK. try **Nearby.** and hit **ctrl+space** to check available methods

Comment: I am getting this all Methods.. Connections, MESSAGES_API,Messages, CONNECTIONS_API, zzbxL, zzbxK, zzbxM

Comment: it requires context as a parameter. In your case you can use **Nearby.getConnections(getActivity())**

Comment: I have added Nearby.getConnections(getActivity()) only.. but the Nearby is not showing any suggestion of  getConnection() method

Comment: Use Nearby.Connections instead of Nearby.getConnections.

Comment: what you are actually trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: i wanted to connect two device using the combination of bluetooth, wifi and ultrasonic audio to have a chat module between them with the use of Google Nearby message API.